# (C++) Is there a way to use a shorthand if statement using return of a function?

Tags: c++, conditional-operator

I'm doing a lot of function calls to a specific function that returns a integer. Now I want to check for every call if the integer returned is higher than the one before that. I want to create a nice oneliner to prevent a lot of code duplication.

What I currently have:

```
int callFunction() {
  int result = // do something;
  return result;
}


int main() {
  int result = 0;
  int tmpResult = 0;

  //call 1
  int tmpResult = callFunction();
  result = (tmpResult > result) ? tmpResult : result;
  
  // call 2
  int tmpResult = callFunction();
  result = (tmpResult > result) ? tmpResult : result;
  
  // call 3
  int tmpResult = callFunction();
  result = (tmpResult > result) ? tmpResult : result;

  // log the highest result
}
```

Ideally I want the return of the callFunction() directly parsed into the result, given it's higher than the current result.

I tried this:

```
result = (callFunction() > result) ? callFunction() : result;
```

But I don't want to call the same function twice if that's not necessary.
Is there a way to get this oneliner without calling the function twice?

Comment: You mean like `result = std::max(callFunction(), result);` ?

Comment: Note that you should `#include <algorithm>` to use `std::max`.

Comment: And maybe put it in a loop?

Comment: Or `return (tmpResult=callFunction()) > result ? tmpResult : result;`

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie bah, that won't pass my code review! X-(

Comment: They don't allow nested assugnments?

Comment: `result = std::max({0, callFunction(), callFunction(), callFunction()});`?

Comment: *"I want to create a nice oneliner to prevent a lot of code duplication."* -- some people call this "writing a function to do the task" (although in this case, your standard library's authors have already written a family of functions to do the task).